# Eating in a non-kosher household

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, children-parenting, family-members

I am a converted Jew (mother is not Jewish, father is) who has recently began keeping Kosher. My mother is an excellent cook, and I greatly enjoyed eating what she made growing up. I still would like to be able to go eat at my parent's for dinner, but I know they do not keep Kosher, be it keeping separate dishes/sinks or even checking labels. Can I eat at their house if my mother promises to cook a vegetarian, kosher-style meal?

Comment: The answer is probably not, but it isn't impossible.  If you brought your own kosher utensils and the food was exempted from Bishul Akum, and was kosher, and the cooking implements used were kashered ahead of time, it could be done (I'm probably forgetting a few other things, so I won't make this an answer)

Comment: The above assumes you're Orthodox; if you're Conservative, it becomes much easier to justify this.

Comment: Why don't you have her come cook at your (kosher) house?

Comment: @Shokhet it's possible that there are leniencies available for parents that aren't available generally.  (I realize that in the case of a *ger* it's not a halachic parent, but this question comes up for *baalei t'shuvah* too.  I actually have a book downstairs called something like "What do you mean you can't eat in my house?!" for BTs.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hm. I think I've seen that title, actually, but I don't believe I've read it. ....I thought I saw this question here before, so I [searched](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=non+kosher+home+is%3Aq) for it....I may have been thinking of [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15705/5323) instead, which does include the element of family. IAE, [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12477/5323) [questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30166/5323) (from that search) are related.

Comment: Is this is a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15705, @Shokhet, y'all?

Answer (score 2):

No.

A "vegetarian, kosher-style meal" [is not necessarily kosher](/q/15532); even a vegan one [is not necessarily kosher](/q/30363). That said, there are [some foods](/q/936) you can eat in their house, such as (usually) whole raw fruits. If this question is relevant to you practically, then [consult your rabbi](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).